# How to achieve native token transfers between accounts in ink?

Tags: ink, smart-contract

I would like to know how to achieve native token transfers between different accounts in ink? For example, I would like to initiate transfer from Alice(which will be the caller) to Bob within a method, how should I do? The transferred value should be calculated within the method which cannot be predetermined, thus cannot be included with the call and cannot be read by self.env().transferred_value(). So far I could only find `self.env().transfer()` for transfers from contract to an address. It should be something similar to `to.call{value}(“”)` in solidity.

Answer (score 2):

If you talk about ink! that means the contract needs to be involved in the fund transfer.

1. Alice signes the tx and includes funds with the call
2. The contract reads the value used in tx with: `self::env().transferred_value()`
3. The contract sends funds to Bob by using: `self.env().transfer()`

something like this code:

```
#[ink(message, payable)]
fn send_funds(&mut self, to: AccountId)-> Result<(), ink_env::Error>{
    let balance = Self::env().transferred_value();
    Self::env().transfer(to, balance)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: How `transferred_value()` is determined while contract contract execution?

Comment: Is there a way to initiate transfer inside the method? I mean in my project's logic, the transferred value will be calculated within the method which cannot be predetermined, thus cannot be included with the call and cannot be read by self.env().transferred_value()

Comment: You can only transfer value that is on the contract's account. If you add balance on the contract with some other payable method, you can still use `transfer(to, balance)`to send funds. To check contract balance use [ink_env::balance()](https://docs.rs/ink_env/3.3.1/ink_env/fn.balance.html)

Comment: @Maario [`ink_env::balance()`](https://docs.rs/ink_env/3.3.1/ink_env/fn.balance.html), returns executed contract balance, if we send this balance using `transfer(to, ink_env::balance())`, does all balance of the contract transferred? if so, will contract still exists with 0 balance?